# Excel: 'We can't update some of the links in your workbook' - How to turn off warning

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have two files:

File 1: Large dataset, updated daily manually by staff.

File 2: Analysis of dataset, used by other staff.

Whenever I open File 2, I get the prompt 'We can't update some of the links in your workbook right now'.O

I have tried:

Selected 'Don't display the alert and update links' in the Edit Links - Startup Prompt.

Opening File 1 before File 2. Still get prompt.

Changing the Options to uncheck 'Ask to update automatic links'. Still get the prompt.

Changed settings in the Trust Center about updating links automatically.

What I don't understand is why it's not working in this one workbook. I have another set, all with the same settings as above, and I don't get prompts when I open the files.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It's because there are links in your workbook to another data source. Go to Data tab -> Connections section -> Edit Links. You can click break link to remove it. If you don't need the link, that is.

I think you may be aware of the link, so I considered deleting this post, but it is still a legitimate solution, so I'm leaving it for other users.

Comment: The link needs to be there, read the post again. One file references data from the other. I have everything set to automatically update links, but I still get the warning. That is the issue.